# var versus atom for runtime constants

Tags: clojure

Based on command-line input, I need to set some run-time constants which a number of downstream functions are going to use.  The code in those functions may execute in other threads so I am not considering the "declare var and use binding macro" combination.  What are the pros/cons of using a var (with alter-var-root) for this versus using an atom? That is,

```
(declare *dry-run*) ; one of my constants

(defn -main [& args]
   ; fetch command line option
   ;(cli args ...)
   (alter-var-root #'*dry-run* (constantly ...))
   (do-stuff-in-thread-pool))
```

versus

```
(def *dry-run* (atom true))   

(defn -main [& args]
   ; fetch command line option
   ;(cli args ...)
   (reset! *dry-run* ...)
   (do-stuff-in-thread-pool))
```

If there is another option besides these two which I should consider, would love to know.

Also, ideally I would've preferred not to provide an initial val to the atom because I want to set defaults elsewhere (with the cli invocation), but I can live with it, especially if using the atom offers advantages compared to the alternative(s).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write-once values are exactly the use case promises are designed for:

```
(def dry-run (promise))

(defn -main []
  (deliver dry-run true))

(defn whatever [f]
  (if @dry-run
    ...))
```

Comment: Thanks for your tip. Is the value delivered to the promise going to be visible in all threads (automatic binding conveyance), or do I need to do something special for that?

Comment: Binding conveyance does not enter the picture at all for anything but vars. A promise is just a Clojure object which, when dereferenced, will produce the value that was delivered to it, or block until such a value arrives. Threads are no more relevant than they would be if you defined a global hash-map.

Comment: Thanks. Since my value is a run-time constant it qualifies as a write-once value.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK `alter-var-root` only guarantees synchronized variable value changing and doesn't guarantee safe reading during this change. On other hand the `atom` really provides atomically change the state of identity.

If you don't want provide an initial value you can just set it to `nil`:

```
(def *dry-run* (atom nil))
```

Answer (score 2):

What is wrong with just using a var and `alter-var-root`? You set up the new value in your startup function, before you really kick-off the workers. So there is no race in reading. And you can save the `@` everywhere you need the value.